# How do I get my bottom "Buy now" text to center with my other text? note: I'm only a couple weeks into learning

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
  .new-title {
    font-family: arial;
    text-align: center;
    color: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .macbook-title {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .supercharge-title {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  .price-title {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }


  .buy-title {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 1000px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
</style>

<p class="new-title">New</p>
<p class="macbook-title">MacBook Pro</p>
<p class="supercharge-title">Supercharged for pros</p>
<p class="price-title">From $1999</p>
<p>
  <span class="buy-title">Buy</span>>
</p>
```

New

MacBook Pro

Supercharged for pros

From $1999

Buy>

I approached it like the rest of my code, with text-align: center; but for some reason it doesn't move like my other text does, I've also tried margining but that doesn't seem like an efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

change your `.buy-title` to this. [Live Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/krgta1zy/)

```css
  .buy-title {
    display:block;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: fit-content;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do so, But I suggest as you are very new to CSS you must go with `CSS Flex`. It will definetely boost your CSS skills.

You can see the snippet below how simple it is.

Refer this to learn more about flex: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.new-title {
    font-family: arial;
    text-align: center;
    color: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .macbook-title {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .supercharge-title {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  .price-title {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }


  .buy-title {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p class="new-title">New</p>
<p class="macbook-title">MacBook Pro</p>
<p class="supercharge-title">Supercharged for pros</p>
<p class="price-title">From $1999</p>
<p>
  <span class="buy-title">Buy</span>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I haven't heard of that until now, I'm definitely going to learn it!

Comment: Cool!! @Baddusername